# Not getting all URL's with loop

Tags: c#

I am looping throw my docTab.Rows which is a Dataset Table connected to a method which is returning six results.

What I am trying to do is to loop throw does results get the field from my table in which I am interested most URL in my case. and then set this URL as a path so that I can copy all the files that I need

```
    foreach (var row in docTab.Rows)
    {   
        var sourceFile = "//ch-s-0001535/G/inetpub/DocAddWeb/DataSource/"+docTab.Rows[0]["URL"].ToString();
        string targetPath = rootFolderAbsolutePath;
        File.Copy(sourceFile, rootFolderAbsolutePath+Path.GetFileName(sourceFile),overwrite:true);
    }
```

My issue is that I only get 1 file and always the same , never seen the other six even do my loop goes throw 6 times

Comment: In the first line of your loop `replace` `docTab.Rows` to `row `

Comment: Replace `var sourceFile = "//ch-s-0001535/G/inetpub/DocAddWeb/DataSource/"+docTab.Rows[0]["URL"].ToString();` **to** `var sourceFile = "//ch-s-0001535/G/inetpub/DocAddWeb/DataSource/"+row[0]["URL"].ToString();`

Comment: @Chaitanya then I am getting the error cannot apply indexing with[] to expression of type object

Comment: Replace foreach 'var' to 'DataRow'. Then it will loop through all rows of dataset table.

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri YES! GJ thanks allot feel free to post it as answer

Comment: @SuperDoc Checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach (DataRow row in docTab.Rows)
 {
    var sourceFile = "//ch-s-0001535/G/inetpub/DocAddWeb/DataSource/" + row["URL"].ToString();
          //Your code
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace foreach 'var' to 'DataRow'. Then it will loop through all rows of dataset table

```
foreach (DataRow row in docTab.Rows)
{
   var sourceFile = "//ch-s-0001535/G/inetpub/DocAddWeb/DataSource/" + row["URL"].ToString();
      //Your code
}
```